# Why project structure files and directories not show in PyCharm

Tags: file, directory, pycharm, structure, jetbrains-ide

I clone a project from *gitlab* and when open in **PyCharm** not show my files and folders. Of course show them in **Project Files** tab but not recognize any **namespace** of project.

[image]

Comment: Currently the files don't correspond to an open project. You need to open a new project choosing the base directory so PyCharm can create the `.idea` folder. You can also try to choose the base directory as [content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html) and see if that alone solves the problem.

Comment: @bad_coder I cant find project structure in PyCharm. 2021.2.3 Professional Edition.

Comment: It can happen that you opened PyCharm in [LightEdit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69786191). Go to `File` `>` `New Project` and open a new project using the base directory of your cloned repository. That way when the IDE creates the `.idea` folder the project structure view will be working. (That is essentially the problem, you cloned the repository but didn't go through the step of opening it as a project.)